# Nativescript rotate animation with infinite iteration not working

Tags: javascript, android, typescript, webview, nativescript

I want to rotate label with infinite iteration, currently it is working fine on iOS devices but on android it only rotates for 2 sec and then stop.

Below is my CSS code

```css
.fas {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free", "fa-solid-900";
    font-weight: 900;
}

.spin {
    animation-name: rotate;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes rotate {
    from { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<Label text="rotate value" class="fas spin"></Label>
```

Comment: NativeScript doesn't support Java annotations, so you will have to write the WebInterface in Java library project and use it in your JS / TS code. Most of the functionalities in this case are already covered by [nativescript-webview-ext](https://github.com/Notalib/nativescript-webview-ext) plugin, you could try that.

Comment: @Manoj I am new in Nativescript, I have added this plugin in project but enable to run any of the functionality. Is there any sample project which has implementation of this plugin.

Comment: Just refer the docs, I haven't used the plugin personally but I think you will call emit method on bridge from your webpage and listen to same in your code.

Comment: It's exactly `nsWebViewBridge.emit(eventName, dataToEmit)` from your web page.

Comment: @Manoj Thank You so much, Appreciate it. One question this bridge is used on both webpage and mobile app code to set a communication right?

Comment: Yes, for your use case you listen to event from mobile app code and trigger it from web page code.

Comment: @Manoj : I need to change the question because it is not allowing me to ask more question. Do you have any idea of this question?

Answer (score 17):

I'm not sure if its a bug, can't expect {N} to be inline with Browsers as we are dealing with native elements here. The hack below seems to work,

```
@keyframes rotate {
    0% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    99.9% {transform: rotate(360deg);}
    100% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works on Android now. You again saved me. Appreciate your help.